# Find IP address of second router in daisy chain

Tags: networking, router, ip, home-networking

I have two routers in my home. The downstairs router is the one connected to the modem. Then, I have a second router upstairs which is daisy chained to the first router. I have a server upstairs with port forwarding setup on the upstairs router. The problem is that I cannot find the public IP of my upstairs router because all the whatismyip requests just return the IP of my downstairs router. I can't setup port forwarding on the downstairs router because the downstairs router is my roommate's and I don't really want to mess with it, and it's also too far from my server to use the WiFi from it.

I'm a total noob to networking / home servers, but I think my question boils down to **how do I find the public IP address of the second router in a daisy chain**.

Comment: Ping the whole inter-router subnet nodes from your server. The IP which belongs to WAN of closest router will show TTL value different from TTLs from another nodes.

Comment: If you connected it to the first router on the internal side (normal way to connect) it will not have an external facing IP address. Only the downstairs router will have that

Comment: Putting one NAT gateway behind another like this is called "double NAT", and it's usually a bad idea unless you really know what you're doing and have a good reason for doing it anyway. It's usually better to disable NAT on the second router so that it just transparently bridges packets between the wired Ethernet it's connected to, and its wireless clients. If your router doesn't have an easy way to disable NAT, you can instead disable its DHCP Server service (or set the DHCP address pool so it has no addresses) and connect the upstream Ethernet cable to a LAN port instead of the WAN port.

Comment: What do you mean by "daisy chained" exactly? Is the second router's WAN port connected to anything? (If so, why? It's not connected to a WAN.)

Comment: The second router's WAN port is connected to a LAN port on the first router.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this to work. I assigned my server a static IP with the upstairs router. Then, I set up port forwarding to it. After that, I set up a static IP for the upstairs router with the downstairs router. Then, I enabled port forwarding from the downstairs router to the upstairs router. Finally, I used a free dynamic DNS (mynetgear.com) for the downstairs router. I did have to tamper with my roommate's router, and I don't know if there's any way around that for my situation.